# Jquery Customizable Slider

Tags: jquery

I need to create a jquery slider with following requirements
 1. It should world across all devices(IOS, Android)
 2. It should play videos also
 3. The images should be swippable/slidable.
 4. The images should be dynamically populated through json

Please share your insights and code snippets.

Thanks in advance.

Megha

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you make some research on it?
P.S. Sorry for my inconvenience By mistake I add my question as answer instead of comment to question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   When asking a question, you should be able to provide some code you are working with, what you've tried, and what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an effective solution that I've used on multiple projects...

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

There's a slight learning curve, so you'll have to read up on it, but it should meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but I  want the youtube videos also to be played and the slides to be swippbale as we need to support the slider for multiple devices.

Comment: I have tried swiper sliderhttp://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/ but it does not support youtube videos. Also I want the videos/images to be fetched through json or xml.

Comment: I display videos in flexslider with no trouble. I'm not familiar with swiper.